# If statement batch file trouble

Tags: batch-file

Im having trouble with the following batch file.

```
`@Echo off

:START

set /p answer=Is the internet working? Y/N

if "%answer%"=="Y" (GOTO Label1)
if "%answer%"=="N" (GOTO Label2)
if "TIMER GOES HERE" "==" (GOTO Label1)

:Label1

exit

:Label2 

mkdir c:\Inst

copy "T:\Proxy Settings\Proxy settings1.bat" C:\Inst
timeout /t 10
start "C:\Inst\Proxy settings1.bat"`
```

What i want it to do is to ask if the user if the internet is working and if they select no then run a file. once the file has ran i want it to ask the question again and if it is still not working run a second file. So kind of like the following

```
'Is internet working Y/N

If Y exit

Else Run Settings 1

Once file has ran ask if internet is working

If Y exit

Else Run Settings 2'
```

Comment: So... what's the trouble? You said you have trouble, is there an error happening?

Comment: The trouble is i dont know how to get it to do the second function. I tried to run the code i linked and it doesnt run the registry entry that changes the proxy settings. When im running it doesnt spit out any errors however it doesnt run the files.

Comment: if is case sensitive. If you enter 'y', it won't `goto` anywhere. Use `if /i` to make case insensitive. (maybe that is your problem?)

Comment: `if "timer goes here"`line has no valid syntax. Maybe `choice /?` is what you look for.

Comment: Use *goto :eof* instead of *exit*.  If you run this from a cmd prompt, exit will close the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
@Echo off
:START
set /p answer=Is the internet working? Y/N
if %answer%==y GOTO Label1
if %answer%==n GOTO Label2
if %answer%==Y GOTO Label1
if %answer%==N GOTO Label2
if TIMER GOES HERE "==" GOTO Label1
:Label1
exit
:Label2 
mkdir c:\Inst
```

I take it you have done python as your code looks a bit pythoney. Let me know how it works.